# How to Remove Border of Disabled Button in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a style that I am using which makes the default color of the button content set to whatever `ThemeBrush` is in App.xaml. The button syle displays the button like a normal textblock. I have run into the issue, however, that when the button is disabled in code behind the border shows. How can I modify my solution to remove the border permanently when the button is enabled or disabled?

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>-->
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <!--<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>-->
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <!--<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>-->
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <!--<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>-->
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Set BorderThickness to 0? Remove the Border called ButtonBackground?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a couple things about what you're doing. #1, don't trust the default templates to be a good example. WP is based on silverlight, so for both performance and consistency I'd suggest instead of interacting with multiple properties to accomplish an effect, segregate it to individual objects. In the case of toggling the visibility of something, the [performance docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189071%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#use_visibility) point you towards that idea. So see my revised version for an example that should fix your issue and implement some better practices.

Basically for what you're doing, I stripped off the fluff, and now all that happens is in a disabled state there's a border that will show over the content with the DisabledBrush effectively give you your disabled state, and that's all you're doing.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledState" 
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                   <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="DisabledState" Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Background="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" 
                            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hope this helps, Cheers